# Aspas Inglesas como editar?

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um site que me deparei que um texto terá aspa inglesa, até ai tudo bem é só fazer o código, mas o problema começa quando vou editar sua fonte para ficar maior, a aspa final cria uma altura automática que eu não consegui tirar nem colocando altura fixa, usar position absolute não resolve pq a aspa tem que ficar no final e no começo da frase, então como eu faço para que a aspa final fique corretamente no final do texto?

**IMAGEM**

[image: APAS INGLESAS]

**CÓDIGO CSS**

```css
.noticias .interna H5 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    font: normal bold 23px/33px 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.noticias .interna H5:BEFORE {
    content: "“";
    font: normal bold 50px/33px 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
}
.noticias .interna H5:AFTER {
    content: "”";
    font: normal bold 50px/33px 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Coloque tb seu html com as div etc, fica melhor para te dar uma resposta precisa

Comment: eu já fiz isso antes de postar e o resultado é o mesmo a aspa final vai lá pra cima

Comment: Já pensou numa solução via JavaScript?

Comment: Não pq achei que não seria necessário, mas pelo visto acho que vou ter de procurar um jeito de fazer com!!

Comment: Cara eu postei uma resposta onde consegui ajustar usando `top` mesmo. Mas se não for isso que vc precisa me fala que edito lá se for preciso.

Comment: Seria algo assim usando JS: https://jsfiddle.net/6fk1xdv7/

Comment: Dá até pra colocar a primeira aspas pelo JS tb, pra ficar ao lado da primeira palavra do texto.

Comment: Eu ia colocar imagem mas essa solução ai é melhor vlw acho que vou ficar com ela mesmo

Comment: Vou remover a reposta por enquanto, quando pensar em algo te dou uma ideia

Comment: Cara fiz uns ajuste simples no CSS e acho que agora ficou do jeito que vc queria, caso não queira usar a opção do JS agora vc tem uma opção só com CSS. []´s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução usando JavaScript para inserir a aspas no final do texto. Como você está usando `flex`, inserir uma tag direto no texto faria com que ela ficasse posicionada à direita do texto. Então sugiro que inclua todo o texto numa tag `span` para poder inserir outra contento a aspas estilizada.

Com um `for` você insere a aspas final no final de todos os textos em `<h5><span>`:

```js
var h5 = document.querySelectorAll("h5 span");
for(var x=0; x<h5.length; x++){
   h5[x].innerHTML += "<span>”</span>";
}
```

```css
.noticias .interna H5{
   width:100%;
   display:flex;
   position: relative;
   font:normal bold 23px/33px 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
   text-align:center;
   justify-content:center;
   color:#333333;
   /* padding:0 0 30px 0; removido */
}
.noticias .interna H5:BEFORE{
   content:"“";
   font:normal bold 50px/33px 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
}
/* código abaixo adicionado para pegar o span da aspas */
.noticias .interna h5 span span{
   position: relative;
   font:normal bold 50px/0 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
   top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="noticias">
   <div class="interna">
      <h5>
         <span>
            O Brasil tem posição de destaque em relação ao etanol.
            <br>
            Temos a solução aqui em casa, importar
            <br>
            baterias não vai alimentar a economia local.
         </span>
       </h5>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não adianta colocar um span pq o texto está centralizado a cada linha tem um br no final, então se vc coloca position absolute não vai ficar ao lado do texto automaticamente e sempre no canto entendeu? A aspa tem que acompanhar o texto do jeito normal só que com o tamanho maior

Comment: Entendi, mas o BEFORE também faz com que a primeira aspas fique sempre no canto antes da frase. Você quer que a aspas final fique logo após a última palavra?

Comment: sim se fosse pra ficar no canto de baixo eu já tinha resolvido, tendeu?

Comment: Resposta atualizada! =]

Comment: vlw ai pela ajuda, já marquei como resolvida, pena que não deu pra resolver com css, até agora não entendo por que as aspas criam esta altura sozinha qdo aumentam sua fonte, mas o importante é que demos um jeito

Comment: Com jeitinho saiu uma opção só com CSS ;)

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT

Fiz essa nova resposta pois acredito que a anterior não era a melhor opção, tanto semanticamente quanto aos recursos que o CSS oferece que deveriam ser usado da forma correta e não com "jeitinho" para funcionar.

Primeiramente veja que o HTML tem a tag `<q> ... </q>` onde Q significa *quote* Veja o que diz a documentação da Mozilla sobre essa tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q

> O elemento HTML `<q>` indica que o texto em anexo é uma cotação curta em linha. A maioria dos navegadores modernos implementam isso cercando o texto entre aspas.

Depois veja que o CSS tem o atributo `quote` onde é possível customizar o tipo de *aspa* que vc quer utilizar.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/quotes

> A propriedade CSS `quote` indica como os agentes do usuário devem renderizar aspas.

Ex:

```
q {
  quotes: '“' '”';
}
```

Agora veja que quando a tag `<q>` é renderizada pelo browser ele inclui dois pseudo-elementos `::before` e `::after` automaticamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Agora a resposta que acredito ser mais adequada**

Primeiro não coloque o `::before` e `::after` na tag `<h5>`, nesse caso use a tag `<q>` dentro da tag de título: `<h5><q>...`

Agora basta definir o tipo de `quote` que vc quer *(aspas inglesas)*, e depois estilizar os `::before` e `::after` da tag `<q>`

Veja como fica o resultado das aspas customizadas e das aspas default colocadas direto dentro do text. ***OBS:** Deixei os comentários no código*

```css
div {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h5 {
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align:center;
}
q::before, q::after {
    quotes: '“' '”' ; /* estilo das aspas */
    color: red; /* cor das aspas */
    font-size: 40px; /* tamanho da fonte das aspas */
    position: relative;
    top: 4px; /* altura das aspas relativas ao texto, ajuste ótico devido a variação do tamanho da fonte das aspas*/
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h5><q>sit amet consectetur</q></h5>
    <h5><q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, consequatur.</q></h5>
    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor "sit amet consectetur" adipisicing elit.</h5>
</div>
```

---

***Uma opção só com CSS***

Olha eu não sei se tem algum outro CSS influenciando no seu código, mas aqui está normal fazendo um ajuste no `top` e `bottom` com `position:absolut` OBS: Eu separei o *shorthand* da `font` pra ficar melhor de visualizar os atributos.

No `top:` vc controla a altura que quiser assim como no `bottom` e usa `margin` e `padding` para dar o espaçamento entre as aspas e o texto.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.interna {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.noticias .interna H5{ 
    width:100%; 
    line-height: 33px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
    text-align:center; 
    color:#333333; 
    padding-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}    
.noticias .interna H5::before{ 
    content: "“";
    line-height: 33px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5rem;
    margin-left: -1.5rem;
}
.noticias .interna H5::after{ 
    content: "”";
    line-height: 33px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.5rem;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="noticias">
    <div class="interna">
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor psa!</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="noticias">
    <div class="interna">
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sitanimi eveniet laborum ipsa a!</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="noticias">
    <div class="interna">
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur hic ullam fugiat! Veniam accusamus voluptates animi eveniet laborum ipsa a!</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O problema é que o conteúdo no H5 não pode ter largura nenhuma, pq eu não sei quando texto ele vai colocar, a quebra de linha será feita pelo cliente dando um enter que no editor do site será um br, então usar position absolute não serve e mesmo que tivesse largura não daria pra colocar a aspa no final do texto com position abosolute

Comment: @user4451 o tamanho eu coloquei só pra visualizar melhor, ele não é determinante na minha resposta, minha dúvida agora é se vc quer que a última aspa fique no final da última palavra é isso, tipo embaixo junto com a última linha?

Comment: quero que fique no final do texto após a ultima palavra não no canto deixando um espaço

Comment: @user4451 então é só tirar um padding-bottom default que todo elemento H tem e colocar em vez de top no after um bottom negativo pra ajusta. Já editei a resposta olha lá como ficou

Comment: não adianta ele fica no canto com um espaço em branco acho que a saída pra isso vai ser um criar uma imagem das duas aspas e colocar como imagem, ai eu acho que fica certo, volto aqui pra saber se deu certo